# Should Kreyszig's Functional Analysis or Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis be read for an introduction into more advanced analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, self-learning

I realise they are quite different in their approach and material covered, but they share the central stuff like normed/Banach/Hilbert spaces, Hahn-Banach theorem etc. Not really understanding what awaits me in those books besides these things, I have a dilemma which book to read first.

Which book and why would you feel is more relevant for the first steps into more advanced analysis?

Comment: Lebesgue integration is important and fun, and is necessary for many of the applications of functional analysis. So I would say for most people it would make sense to start with Rudin's book.

Comment: It is said that Rudin's books are graduate texts ([Origins of Baby/Papa/Mama/Big Rudin](//math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/3816655)). Kreyszig's book are undergraduate text